# How to make navigation bar drop down from top to take up entire page?

Tags: html, css

I know that I have created a similar question to this, but I guess I was not clear enough in my previous question. I am still learning and have researched this for literally hours and have hit a brick wall. And I would really, really appreciate some help.

Here is my website when it is at it's maximum width:

[image]

Everything here is great, nothing wrong.

Now here is my website when it's maximum width is 767 pixels:
[image]

Nothing is wrong here either. When my website's max width is 767px you can see a menu button appears on the top left (as shown in the image above).

I would like it so that when I click that menu button, the navigation bar will extend to the bottom of the page and will display the menu buttons shown in the first image.

Here is a blueprint to better understand:

[image]

How should I go about this? Do I create two nav bars? Do I stick with only one nav bar?

Here is my code so far...

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="first-nav">
    <div class="first-nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><button onclick="expandNav()"><i class="fal fa-bars"></i></button></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-connectdevelop"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Records</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Moderator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <nav id="second-nav">
    <div class="second-nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ban</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Warn</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Records</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Moderator</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Out</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="main-content">

  </div>
</div>
<script>

</script>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.first-nav-bar {
  width: 82%;
}

#first-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  height: 44px;

  background: #040406;
}

#first-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;

  height: 44px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  list-style-type: none;
}

#first-nav a {
  display: inline;

  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#first-nav  ul li:first-child {
  display: none;
}

#first-nav ul li:nth-child(2) i {
  font-size: 22px;
}

#first-nav ul li:nth-child(2):hover a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

#first-nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #939393;
}

#first-nav ul li:nth-child(9) i, ul li:last-child i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-content {
  height: calc(100vh - 44px);
  width: 100%;
  background: #131218;
}

#second-nav {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #first-nav ul button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
  }

  #first-nav ul li:first-child {
    display: flex;
    border: none;
  }

  #first-nav ul li:nth-child(3), #first-nav ul li:nth-child(4), #first-nav ul li:nth-child(5), #first-nav ul li:nth-child(6),
  #first-nav ul li:nth-child(7), #first-nav ul li:nth-child(8), #first-nav ul li:nth-child(9), #first-nav ul li:nth-child(10) {
    display: none;
  }

  #second-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    height: 100vh;

    background: black;
  }

  #second-nav ul {
    display: flex;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    flex-direction: column;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    list-style-type: none;
  }

  #second-nav li {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }

  #second-nav a {
    color: white;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
}
```

As you can probably tell, I have tried using two navigation bars but have not been successful. You will also notice that I tried doing it myself but have failed, just thought I'd share my work to show that I have attempted working on it.

**Note:** I am trying to get it so that the menu only shows when the button is pressed.

Comment: `How should I go about this? Do I create two nav bars? Do I stick with only one nav bar?`, those are only questions you can answer. Stack Overflow isn't really meant to give design advice or help with design decisions. What exactly are you looking to do?

Comment: @CharlieFish It is not really design help. I am having trouble displaying the menu bar when the menu item is clicked. I jut would like it so that when the menu button is clicked, a menu will pop down taking up the entire page's height and all the menu buttons will be centered within that menu window that is extended throughout the page.

Comment: And what is the current result? What is currently happening?

Comment: The current result is the buttons are somewhat centered? I do not really know how to explain it. This is really confusing. My end result is for it to look like Apple's website nav bar. If you go to Apple.com and resize the page so that it's at it's minimum width and you click that menu button on the top left, that is what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: The problem looks to be `justify-content: center;`. You are centering all those items. If that isn't the result you are looking for changing that might produce more of the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @CharlieFish that is what I am looking for. But how would I hide the menu so that it would not appear unless if the menu button is clicked? I tried setting the height to 0 but that didn't work. Should I use display none?

Comment: I would try `display: none`, yes. If that doesn't work might need to go into your dev tools and play around with the inspect tool to figure out how to hide it.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a try. Sorry to bother you again, but I feel as though the content in the menu is not dead centered on the horizontal axis. Do you see what am I talking about or is that just me? Edit: also, how would I hide the bottom content past the menu? I tried using overflow: hidden but had no luck.

Comment: It looks pretty centered to me. You would have to use some type of pixel measuring tool to find out for sure, or use the inspect panel and see if there is any margin, padding, or borders that are causing it to not be aligned properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to not have the nav items centered on the page you have to remove the `justify-content: center;`.

`justify-content: center;` will cause all the items to be centered within the flex-box container.

In order to hide the menu so that it won't appear unless the menu is open I would try using `display: none;` to hide that menu.